# Why is the result of VarPtr(ByVal str) the same as StrPtr(str) ? (VB6)

Tags: vb6

In VB6 `VarPtr` should return the address of the variable, in this case the address of the variable `str` which is allocated on stack, and holds a pointer to a string in memory. `StrPtr` (or `StrPtr`) should return the address of the allocated string in the memory. `ByVal` should just create a copy, but in this case, it works strangely:

```
Dim str As String
str = "asd"
Debug.Print VarPtr(str)
Debug.Print VarPtr(ByVal str)
Debug.Print StrPtr(str)
```

The result is:

```
1636452 
110882980 
110882980
```

Why is the result of `VarPtr(ByVal str)` the same as `StrPtr(str)` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings passed `ByVal` pass the address of the first character of the containing C string in the BStr. `StrPtr` does the same.

There are two reasons that spring to mind for doing this. Passing Unicode to API calls and string building.

**Passing Unicode to API calls**

You could use `StrPtr` on a string rather than a byte array when sending Unicode strings to API functions.

```
Dim ByteArr() as Byte
Var1="My Text"
ByteArr = Var1
APICall(ByteArr(0))
APICall(StrPtr(Var1))
```

Should both pass a Unicode string to an API functions. Unicode strings are converted to ANSI strings when using the `declare` statement as Win 95 didn't do unicode.

**String Building**

On the other hand if you are string building, then that is built in to VBA using the `Left`, `Right`, and `Mid` **statements**, not **functions** (they are overloaded).

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Var As String
    Var = "gggggggggggg"
    MsgBox StrPtr(Var)
    Mid(Var, 1, 2) = "xx"
    MsgBox StrPtr(Var) & " - " & Var
End Sub
```

> **ByVal Versus ByRef**
>
> Some authors like to say that the ByVal keyword is overloaded for
>   strings, meaning that it takes on a different meaning when applied to
>   strings than when applied to other variables. Frankly, I don't see it.
>   Writing:
>
> ```
> ByVal str As String
> ```
>
> tells VB to pass the contents of the BSTR (actually the ABSTR), which is the pointer to the character array. Thus, ByVal is acting
>   normally--it just happens that the content of the BSTR is a pointer to
>   another object, so this simulates a pass by reference. Similarly:
>
> ```
> ByRef str As String
> ```
>
> passes the address of the BSTR, as expected.

*Win32 API Programming with Visual Basic*,  *Chapter 6 Strings*, O'Reilly, from *MSDN Library October 2001*

> **StrPtr**
>
> Strings in Visual Basic are stored as BSTR's. If you use the VarPtr on
>   a variable of type String, you will get the address of the BSTR, which
>   is a pointer to a pointer of the string. To get the address of the
>   string buffer itself, you need to use the StrPtr function. This
>   function returns the address of the first character of the string.
>   Take into account that Strings are stored as UNICODE in Visual Basic.
>
> To get the address of the first character of a String, pass the String
>   variable to the StrPtr function.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Dim lngCharAddress as Long
> Dim strMyVariable as String
> strMyVariable = "Some String"
> lngCharAddress = StrPtr(strMyVariable)
> ```
>
> You can use this function when you need to pass a pointer to a
>   UNIOCODE string to an API call.

*HOWTO: Get the Address of Variables in Visual Basic Q199824* Microsoft Knowledge Base, MSDN October 2001.

`VarPtr` is not part of the VBA/VB6 language, therefore companies that implement VBA (like Corel) may not implement it in their VBA. The VBA spec is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851.aspx

Comment: There are no `Left` or `Right` statements in VB6 -- only `Mid`/`Mid$` can be used as the target of an assignment.